# Styling The ListView Header

Tags: xamarin.android, android

I'm using the Holo.Light theme, and I'm trying to customize the ListView Header. The default background is gradient, and the text color is blue. I would like to change from blue to another color, but I'm having difficulties finding the element that changes the color. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I have marked this to be closed because: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. (..)". **So in short, what have you tried?** Your question can also be closed because you are seeking an off-site resource or tutorial.

Comment: I think you're jumping the gun here big guy. I wrote a leading statement to my question, then I asked for the name of the element which would answer my question. An element is part of the code. So in short, I feel if you better understood the api you would know better. Furthermore, I am not seeking an off-site resource or tutorial. I have no idea where that came from. I am actually looking for more constructive feedback than this. Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask What I see in your question is: "What is wrong with my code, how can I change the element?". However, you have not provided any code, nor shown any effort into solving the problem yourself. You haven't even proof read your question. Ask a proper question and show some effort maybe? Something like an example of what you are attempting to do will also help a lot.

Comment: I can see how my question doesn't look like I was showing any effort, which was not my intention. I phrased it like that because I was looking for the least amount of help. I did not want someone to do my work, thats why I asked to be pointed in the right direction, which you took as me asking for an outside website or tutorial. I can see how you would not understand that because of your misinformed comments so far. Thats ok, I take your criticism, and I will do better next time to avoid situations like this. Thanks for your help cheeseburgerman.